# Actor hierarchy design guidance, how and when to destroy child actors

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I am creating a play app that is just a http api wrapper around my actors.

I want to create an actor that will send off emails for things like:

1. registration emails
2. password reminders

I need help understanding how I should create child actors, and **who is responsible for destroying the child actors and how.**

```
object EmailActorProtocol {
  case class Registration(userId: Int)
}

class EmailActor(emailService: EmailService) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
   import EmailActorProtocol._

   def receive = {
      case Registration(userId) => emailService.sendRegistration(userId)
      case _ => log.info("catch all")
   }
}
```

Now at my API layer I will have:

```
object EmailApiController extends Controller {
    def registration = Action[BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>
       val messageResult = request.body.validate[RegistrationMessage]
       messageResult.fold(
         errors => { .... }
         registrationMsg => {
           val emailActor = system.actorOf(Props[new EmailActor(emailService)])
           emailActor ! registrationMsg
           Ok(Json.toJson(...)) 
         }
       )
    }
}
```

So I need guidance on the following (using the above skeleton structure as what I have so far):

1. I'm creating a new EmailActor for each API call, **how should I go about destroying the actor**?
2. Would it make more sense to create another actor so it goes like:  system => EmailActorParent => EmailActor ?

Note:  The email service is simple a wrapper around a 3rd party email provider like MailChimp.  It is going to be **a blocking call** I presume if that matters.

Comment: Nice title; if taken out of context ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the structure is not bad as long as it's a simple application. In a more sophisticated environment, you would like to use and email actor manager and so on. But in these particular case, it looks good to me to have an independent actor to handle each email-sending task (since the call is blocking and you can isolate functionality like this and reuse your emailing actors later maybe in another project). In order to shutdown the actor, you have two options:

1) You can simply send a `PoisonPill` message to the actor after sending the `Registration` message like this:

```
val emailActor = system.actorOf(Props[new EmailActor(emailService)])
emailActor ! registrationMsg
emailActor ! PoisonPill // kill the actor after sending the message
Ok(Json.toJson(...))
```

2) Or you can make the emailing actor to "suicide" like this:

```
def receive = {
  case Registration(userId) => 
    emailService.sendRegistration(userId)
    context.stop(self)
  case _ => log.info("catch all")
}
```

I hope it helped ))

Comment: In your first option, if I pass poisonPill, the call to emailActor ! registrationmsg is non-blocking right?  So it might destroy the actor before it finished when it gets passed poisonpill?  or that goes in the inbox and is executed in serial order.

Comment: It's executed in sequence. It must finish the previous message before "drinking the pill".

Comment: do you mind explain in your answer why I might need an 'email actor manager' in a more complex scenerio?  b/c simple things end up getting complicated eventually :)

Comment: Not really sure, but in case you want to have more control over the process of emailing (making some statistics about the number of emails sent, to who, when, if you want some acknowledge that the sending actor didn't fail, and in case it failed, handle the failure and so on), then you may not want to do all that from the actor that spawns the emailing actors, but you would like to have a more centralized entry point to this process which manages the details in order to not mix responsibilities.